# How to mark all text in DatePicker and Timepicker on Mouse Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, timepicker

Is there any option to select all text in Datepicker/timepicker on mouse focus?
There is no SelectAll() function.

Answer (score 1):

OK, resolved my problem. We need to find included TextBox in DatePicker, like this:

```
private void StartDate_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var dp = sender as DatePicker;
    DatePickerTextBox dptb = (DatePickerTextBox)dp.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", dp);
    dptb.SelectAll();
}
```